# Линукс после Линуса

Tags: linux

Вот задался тут таким вопросом. Насколько мне известно, Линус Торвальдс является главным координатором проекта Linux. От его личного решения зависит, включать те или иные предлагаемые изменения в код ядра. Кроме того, он, кажется, обладает правами на сам бренд Linux. Предположим, что с ним что-то случилось (не дай Бог, но все под Богом ходим). Что тогда будет с проектом Linux? Кто возьмет и вообще имеет право взять на себя возглавление этого проекта?

Comment: А я думал, что ядро идёт под gpl очередной версии. И ситуация определяется условиями лицензии.

Comment: @mikillskegg, ты серьезно?

Comment: Возможно сказывается близость Нового года. Да и прошедший Конец Света...

Comment: Развалится на несколько более-менее независимых ядер. Часть из них будет поддерживаться крупными компаниями.

Comment: @alexlz, GPL - это для создания собственной версии ядра. А вот ванильное ядро координируется лично Торвальдсом, в отличии от того же FreeBSD. А вообще, я не пью.

@avp, очень может быть. Или еще вариант: разработчики скоординируются и создадут коллективный разум, который и подхватит mainstream.

Comment: @mikillskegg (лёгкий троллинг on) про "пью" и "алкоголь" у меня в комментарии нет ни слова. Специально проверил. 

А что касается Торвальдса: ну отойдёт он от дел (надеюсь подобру-поздорову), уговорят кого-нибудь другого. Времена, когда linux кроме энтузиастов никому не нужен был, закончились ещё в прошлом тысячелетии. И фирмы-спонсоры, надеюсь, вдохновят сообщество на продолжение этой истории.

Comment: valve заберет полностью =)

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо. Успокоили мою душу.

Answer (score 22):

думаю, никаких проблем не будет. Хотя Линус координирует ядро, у него налажена целая сеть помощников (вроде Генералами и Лейтенантами называются), которые четко знают свои обязанности). Например, есть люди, которые поддерживают текущее ядро (то, что в продакшине) и так далее. Поэтому, скорее всего будет просто как в Ватикане - Генералы соберутся и выдвинут лидера.

Answer (score 9):

*Автобусы признаны опасными*, эта история с *Python*, тогда была создана *[Python Software Foundation](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Software_Foundation) (PSF)*. Источник Марк Лутц - Программирование на Python. 4-е издание. I том стр. 83

> Организации PSF  предшествовала
>   организация PSA – группа, которая
>   первоначально была образована в
>   ответ на когда-то давно возникшее в
>   телеконференции Python обсуждение
>   полусерьезного вопроса: «Что будет, 
>   если Гвидо попадет под автобус?»

В **Linux** похожая ситуация,есть сообщество которое разрабатывает, а Линус им руководит. Достаточно почитать интервью Линуса за 2012 год,благо их 2-3